Restrict user logons to Windows VMs with Log On To from a non-domain connected machine
I am trying to restrict users in my domain environment to only be able to log onto certain Windows VMs that I specify in Active Directory. There is the Log On To... button within AD Users and Computers that does this, but it seems that this button only works if the machine they are logging onto the VM from is one that is also in this allowed list.
This is a problem, because the users are not logging on from a domain-joined Windows machine - they are connecting from a Chromebox with a Linux environment and an RDP client installed (Remmina, not that this makes much difference). I cannot join these machines to the domain, for obvious reasons.
Is there a simple way to do what I want to do here? I'm assuming at this point I'm going to have to go down the GPO route, unfortunately.
